# Passing mouse coordinates from pyautogui to direct input causes the the mouse to move

Tags: python

Using pyautogui to get coordinates from the mouse then controlling it with direct input to move causes unexplainable results.

```
mouse_pos = get_mouse_pos()
print(mouse_pos)
x = mouse_pos[0]
y = mouse_pos[1]

direct_input.MouseMoveTo(x, y)
mouse_pos = get_mouse_pos()
print(mouse_pos)


Output:
Point(x=243, y=67)
Point(x=486, y=134)
```

The numbers from the second print should never change since im not changing the coordinates the mouse should not move. Can anyone explain given the following what causes the mouse to move?

```
#Code to move the mouse and other stuff..

#Code for direct input
import ctypes
import time

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput


# C struct redefinitions
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def MouseMoveTo(x, y):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.mi = MouseInput(x, y, 0, 0x0001, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra))

    command = Input(ctypes.c_ulong(0), ii_)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(command), ctypes.sizeof(command))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PressKey(0x11)
    time.sleep(1)
    ReleaseKey(0x11)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Using direct input to get coordinates of mouse also yields the same results as using pyautogui, and passing those also causes the mouse to move to different coordinates on the screen, so issue is not with the coordinates i get.

Comment: For god sake. Its relative to the current position. Thanks i solved it myself. Time to get a duck.